# Typedef in traits vs typedef in class

Tags: c++, templates, eigen, traits

I'm looking through the Eigen source code for educational purposes. I've noticed that for each concrete class template `X` in the hierarchy, there is an `internal::traits<X>` defined. A typical example can be found in Matrix.h:

```
namespace internal {
template<typename _Scalar, int _Rows, int _Cols, int _Options, int _MaxRows, int _MaxCols>
struct traits<Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> >
{
  typedef _Scalar Scalar;
  typedef Dense StorageKind;
  typedef DenseIndex Index;
  typedef MatrixXpr XprKind;
  enum {
    RowsAtCompileTime = _Rows,
    ColsAtCompileTime = _Cols,
    MaxRowsAtCompileTime = _MaxRows,
    MaxColsAtCompileTime = _MaxCols,
    Flags = compute_matrix_flags<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols>::ret,
    CoeffReadCost = NumTraits<Scalar>::ReadCost,
    Options = _Options,
    InnerStrideAtCompileTime = 1,
    OuterStrideAtCompileTime = (Options&RowMajor) ? ColsAtCompileTime : RowsAtCompileTime
  };
};
}
```

Now I understand traits to be a way of extending existing classes that you do not want to modify with extra information pertaining to some piece of new code. For example, a user of class template `Foo<class TAllocator>` might want to make use of existing memory allocators `FastAlloc` and `AlignedAlloc`, but Foo needs to know how to interface with these two, and as such a `FooTraits<AlignedAlloc>::allocate()` and `FooTraits<FastAlloc>::allocate()` are defined by the user, which in turn are used by `Foo`.

In this case, however, I don't readily see the problem with just specifying `Scalar` in each derived class, i.e. have `Matrix` define `Matrix::Scalar` using a typedef in the class body. What is the advantage here of using a traits class? Is it just for the purposes of keeping the code clean, i.e. storing all relevant properties of each class in the traits class?

Edit as per Nicol Bolas's response: I understand that some of these typedefs might need to be kept "internal", i.e. should not be exposed to the user, which would explain the traits class. That seems to make sense, however some of these typedefs, such as `Scalar`, *are* available to the outside world, through a typedef in the base class of `Matrix`:

```
template<typename Derived> class MatrixBase
  : public DenseBase<Derived>
{
  public:

    typedef MatrixBase StorageBaseType;
    typedef typename internal::traits<Derived>::StorageKind StorageKind;
    typedef typename internal::traits<Derived>::Index Index;
    typedef typename internal::traits<Derived>::Scalar Scalar;
    typedef typename internal::packet_traits<Scalar>::type PacketScalar;
    typedef typename NumTraits<Scalar>::Real RealScalar;
```

This brings us back to the original question: why isn't `Scalar` just a typedef in `Matrix` itself? Is there any reason aside from stylistic choice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect that, since the traits class is `internal`, that this is the point of using a traits class. That is, to keep these things *internal*. That way, `Matrix` doesn't have a lot of oddball definitions and such, even in its private interface.

Consider the enumeration in your example. Those "enums" (aka: `static constexpr` variables before C++11) don't look like anything that a user should know about. It's an implementation detail, and therefore it should be hidden.

---

`MatrixBase`'s problem is a CRTP issue.

See, `Matrix` would be defined like this:

```
class Matrix : public MatrixBase<Matrix>
```

This partial definition causes 2 things to happen:

1. If `Matrix` has not already been declared as a class type, then it becomes a legal class who's name can be referenced and used.
2. The template `MatrixBase` must be instantiated with the type `Matrix`. *Right now*.

The problem here is that "right now", `Matrix` is an *incomplete* class. The compiler has not yet entered the body of that definition, so the compiler doesn't know anything about its internals. But `MatrixBase` must be instantiated right now.

Therefore, `MatrixBase` cannot use any of the *contents* of the `Derived` class it is provided. If `Matrix` has some typedef in it, `MatrixBase<Derived>` *cannot* see it.

Now, member functions of `MatrixBase<Derived>` can look at definitions in `Derived`, because those are defined after the full class is defined. Even if those functions are defined within the scope of the class.

But you can't have properties of `MatrixBase` access properties of `Derived`. Hence the traits indirection. The traits class can use a specialization based on an incomplete type to expose defines to `MatrixBase`.

Comment: I understand that reasoning for some of those definitions. However, the class from which `Matrix` inherits, `MatrixBase`, publicly defines some of these typedefs, such as `Scalar`, which brings us back to the start - why not define `Scalar` in Matrix to begin with?

Comment: Very clear - thank you very much for taking the time!

Answer (score 4):

The main reason for this `traits` class is to avoid recursive dependencies in the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). Without it, we would end up with something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct Matrix : Base<Matrix<T>> {
  typedef T Scalar;
};
template <typename Derived>
struct Base {
  typename Derived::Scalar foo();
};
```

that fails to compile in some circumstances.
Basically, this class `traits` permits to fully declare `Base<Matrix>` without knowing the declaration of `Matrix`.

Comment: Ah, I see, makes sense. Thanks!